# When overwrite method using Refinement in Ruby

Tags: ruby

there. I make sample code about refinement vs open class. I try to call `String.length`. This script outputs string length on screen.

Why does refinement win open class ??

```
module RefineString
  refine String.singleton_class do
    def length(str)
      str.length
    end
  end
end

def String.length(*)
  fail "'String.length' is bad"
end

using RefineString

puts String.length("hello, world") # displays 12
```

Even if I change sequence, results is same.

```
module RefineString
  refine String.singleton_class do
    def length(str)
      str.length
    end
  end
end

using RefineString # change sequence

def String.length(*)
  fail "'String.length' is bad"
end

puts String.length("hello, world")
```

Comment: Because you `refine` _after_ reopening class. The last call wins.

Comment: I update my question. even if I change sequence, result is same.

Comment: Is this in irb or a file?

Comment: If you change the order, the exception will be raised. Try it yourself accurately before posting to SO, please.

Comment: I am SO confused.  So, Sorry.

Comment: I get it. @mudasobwa wants to say is that before using `using` reopening class wins. OTOH, after using `using`, `refine` wins. Is it correct ?